# What type of screw is this in my subfloor?

Tags: subfloor

The builders of my 15-yr-old home used this screw to affix my subfloor to the metal joists.  I'm putting in new floors and tightening some of the plywood that has loosened over the years.  I'm also adding screws to a few sections where they only used nails.  I want to use what they used but none of the hardware / construction suppliers here on Oahu has ever seen this screw or can explain why it's smooth on the bottom third.  Any idea what this is, why it is designed this way?

[image]

Comment: Reminds me of self drilling sheet metal screws. I could see implementing the same pattern for fastening hardwood to get a large diameter without predrilling and without splitting.

Comment: Why are you so hungry to use the same screws?

Comment: I've removed the "where can I buy it" part of the question because that's explicitly [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Yes, unless you have steel truss joists these aren't the right screws anyway. It may have been a "let's use these up" situation, which is why you have subfloor coming loose--they don't have enough thread to hold in wood joists.

Comment: I should've mentioned in the OP that my home is steel framed and my subfloors are attached to steel joists.  I've added that to the OP.  Thanks.

Comment: Is that a square recess in the head or is it just badly graunched?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like a self drilling wood to metal screw. Here's a [picture from McMaster-Carr's website](https://www.mcmaster.com/90420A720/):

[image]

[image]

They call them "Stainless Steel Drilling Screw, Wood to Metal," described as

> Screws with cutting wings drill a slightly larger hole in the wood to allow for expansion. The wings break off when they contact metal, so the screw can tap the remainder of the hole.

The reason for the long unthreaded drilling tip, I assume, is to allow the drill tip to cut through an underlying metal layer without lifting the wood surface away from the metal layer. The drilling tip takes a bit of time to cut metal, so a fully threaded fastener would lift the wood all the way up to the screw head while the drilling tip worked to penetrate the lower layer of metal. Your fastener has a long unthreaded part to avoid this situation, whereas this more modern fastener has "wings" to overbore the wood and thereby accomplish the same goal with less material.

Comment: Requests for clarification (the last sentence) should be in comments on the original question. Make a statement out of that. ;) +1 anyway

Comment: Self-drilling screws like this are also sometimes labelled as MDF screws - they help to make a hole through the fibreboard rather than pulling up the fibres into a big lump.

Comment: @Tom Carpenter, I just found such screws, but they have a short little self drilling tip. I believe that those long tips are intended to prevent the wood from pulling up to the head while the tip carves through the metal layer. Aligned with your thinking, though, the coarseness of the threads bothers me. I would expect tighter threads like those on sheet metal screws. The OP's are consistent with the McMaster metal-branded screws, though, so I think that breaks any tie.

Comment: Thanks to all and especially popham.  Your explanation for the long unthreaded portion makes sense.  I live in a development that was advertised at the time as a community of "hurricane and termite proof" steel framed homes.  All our homes' subfloors are fastened with these screws.  I was able to find screws locally that are fully threaded, but if my intent is to strengthen the subfloor's bond to the metal joists, will using the fully threaded screws do the opposite (ie. cause the wood to pull up while the tip pierces the metal as you described)? Better to order the unthreaded tips?

Comment: If the wings "overbore" the wood, does that weaken the threads' grip to the wood?

Comment: @chuquy, I could make a bunch of assumptions and offer advice calibrated to my assumptions instead of your exact situation, but that could be bad advice. You should open another question. Your exact subfloor material and joist material should be included in that question.

Comment: @chuquy, I don't think that thread engagement with the wood layer contributes significant strength. The threads should have a strong grip on the underlying metal to close the joint. The closed joint minimizes bending stresses in the fastener.

Comment: @chuquy  The threads don't need to grip the wood - that is what the head is for. The threads are there to grip the metal _beyond_ the wood.